# iPhone Obj-C error: assignment of read-only variable 'prop.149' in Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, variable-assignment

I'm programming an iPhone app using Objective-C.

Here's the error Xcode gives me:

```
error: assignment of read-only variable 'prop.149'
```

The code:

```
// Create CATransition object
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
// Animate over 3/4 of a second
transition.duration = 0.75;
// using the ease in/out timing function
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
// Set transition type
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
// Next line gives error: assignment of read-only variable 'prop.149'
transition.subtype = (flipsideView.hidden == YES ? kCATransitionFromRight : kCATransitionFromLeft);
```

What does the error mean, and how do I fix it?

Comment: I just encountered this error. WTH. (Fixed by using a temporary variable - the casting approach didn't work.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure exactly why, but the compiler is not able to deduce the evaluated type of the result of the ternary operator.  Simply adding an explicit cast seems to work:

```
transition.subtype = (NSString *)(flipsideView.hidden == YES ? kCATransitionFromRight : kCATransitionFromLeft);
```

I'd file this as a compiler bug.

Answer (score 0):

The error means you're setting a property that is read-only.  It looks like the subtype property of CATransition is not a settable property.

Comment: But the property shouldn't be read-only. Here's the documentation:

subtype
Specifies an optional subtype that indicates the direction for the predefined motion-based transitions.

@property(copy) NSString *subtype

The ViewTransitions Sample Project (from Apple) has this line, which works fine:

    transition.subtype = subtypes[random() % 4];

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the documentation says you should be able to assign a value to the subtype property.  I wonder if there is an issue with your line of code that is assigning the subtype.  Are you getting burned by operator precedence?  Try the following:

```
transition.subtype = flipsideView.hidden ? kCATransitionFromRight : kCATransitionFromLeft;
```

Answer (score 0):

This original code fails:

```
transition.subtype = (flipsideView.hidden == YES ? kCATransitionFromRight : kCATransitionFromLeft);
```

But this works:

```
if (flipsideView.hidden == YES) {
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
} else {
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
}
```